# @RefreshScope and /refresh not working for multiple instance

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

@RefreshScope and /refresh not working for updating multiple service instance i know this can be done using spring cloud bus but due to some constraint i can not opt for that is there any alternatives

Comment: Making direct calls to refresh on each instance is the only alternative

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Ribbon to determine the available instances and then call refresh event for all of them. I have not tried this, but seems to be possible as I read in the documentations